# Restlet in Apache Camel without locking browser until completion

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-camel, integration, restlet

We are using Apache Camel integration platform and are updating some data through restlets. We want to know the status of this update as it takes several hours to complete. The problem we have is that we do not get a response from the program until the program has finished. Since the carrier type is of type restlet we have to wait until the job is finished because the browser is waiting for it to finish. We have looked into async ways to do it but it does not seem async is supported by restlet data carrier.

If we dont get any solution to this we have considered running the job using thread pool but we want to know if it is other methods to do jobs async because we might use the camel restlet more extensively later on and having jobs go async is preferable without executing threads every time.

Example code:

```
from("restlet:" +BASE_URL + "test1?restletMethods=get").
    routeId("Test 1").
    log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log.getName(), "Test 1 Started").
    delay(10000).
    log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log.getName(), "Test 1 Complete").
    to("mock:update");
```

As from the code above the browser waits 10 seconds before it responds. We want the browser to be immediately available, as well as getting data during this period.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You have code that adds a delay in the route but you also want the route to be immediately available?

Comment: it is a simulation of some job being done, and then when the job is running i want to get status of that job while it runs. as it is now in a bigger project we cannot get data until the job has finished. We have noticed that camel puts the restlet calls inn a queue and executes in sequence

Comment: Surely it is better to create a mock of that backend service then add a delay? You can simply create a seda queue to some route which all it does is return whatever message you want. Seda works async and that should return control to the browser after the GET.

Comment: I tried using seda but the browser still hangs until seda completes. I have used from restlet -> to seda:test and then put delay in from seda:test

Comment: Got it to work as you said with using seda with this option: .to(seda:test?waitForTaskToComplete=Never. It seems I need to put this option in "to" method as it is not working when putting it in "from" method. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work using SEDA with the option waitForTaskToComplete=Never in the "to" method.

```
from("restlet:"+BASE_URL+"seda?restletMethods=get").
routeId("SEDA async sender").
log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log.getName(), "SEDA test started").
log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log.getName(), "Transfer to SEDA...").
to("seda:test1?waitForTaskToComplete=Never");

from("seda:test1").
threads(4).
routeId("SEDA async receiver").
log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log.getName(), "SEDA active").
delay(4000).
log(LoggingLevel.INFO, log.getName(), "SEDA test complete");
//to("mock:update");
```